# Xdebug Does Not Log Anything to Configured Log File

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Recently I upgraded to PHP 7.4 and couldn't get Xdebug 2.9.6 to work. I'm running an Apache Server on Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to debug the PHP code with a PhpStorm 2019.1 client on an macOS 10.15.5. I have the following config in `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_log = "/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
```

And I verified on the `phpinfo()` page that `Xdebug` is enabled:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Here is the Xdebug section of `phpinfo()`

```
xdebug
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.9.6
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business
Debugger    enabled
IDE Key PHPSTORM
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   /tmp/xdebug.log /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_log_level 7   7
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9001    9001
xdebug.remote_timeout   200 200
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

The problem is after I send my request via browser, Xdebug does not connect to the client (PhpStorm) or log any connection activity to the log file on the web server.

Is there any missing in my config?

Solved:
Turns out there is a firewall on the server that I didn't realize. Set up a ssh reverse tunnel as suggested [here](https://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html) to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some more information on the problem. What did you already try to solve it? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Try placing `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code -- will it make it generate such log? P.S. Make sure you have edited the right php.ini -- on Mac/Linux it's common to have separate php.ini for CLI and web server. Just check `phpinfo()` output captured in a right way (via browser in your case) -- it will show what config files were used.

Comment: @LazyOne Yes my Xdebug config is in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`, which matches what `phpinfo()` shows in the browser returns (I have the exact same config in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` anyways to be safe). I did add `xdebug_break()` to my code but still couldn't get Xdebug to log anything to the `/tmp/xdebug.log` on the web server or connect to my PhpStorm client. I checked apache error log as well and didn't see anything suspicious there either.

Comment: @toydarian thanks:) I tried to ger Xdebug to log something to the configured log location so that I can get some hints but unfortunately Xdebug doesn't even log anything at this point...

Comment: 1) Please post whole Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output (to verify the actual settings). 2) Looks like you are on Linux. It's possible that your SELinux is configured in such way that it may be denying Xdebug activity. If so `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1 ` may help (see this comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206339279/comments/206899645)

Comment: @LazyOne My web server is Ubuntu 18.04 and I don't think I have SELinux enabled. Posted the Xdebug section from `phpinfo()` in the original question above.

Comment: That `phpinfo()` -- is this captured via web page or via CLI? It HAS to be the same way as you are trying to debug (as on Linux it's very common to have separate php.ini for CLI and web server). So double check what config files are used in `phpinfo()` output -- will be at the very top, in first table. Other than that: no better ideas on why it would not generate the logs if settings are correct (those shown above look correct to me). But just in case: please try restarting your computer/OS (sometimes it just resolves the issue)

Comment: @LazyOne The `phpinfo()` above is captured via web page and I confirmed that the php.ini files shown on the web page have the correct Xdebug settings. Yeah I'll keep playing around with it. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses "private temp" directories, so your `xdebug.log` log file is likely available in one of the directories like `/tmp/systemd-private*/tmp/`.

Comment: Thanks [Derick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508057/derick) for pointing out the culprit. You saved my day.  Learned new thing `PrivateTmp`  !  :)